# angularjs jqlite element.css() error ie 11.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jqlite

Error in `backdropElement.css()`

TypeError: The object does not support the property or method "css"

```
var backdropElement = angular.element('<div class="alert-backdrop"/>');
backdropElement.css({
  position: 'fixed',
  top: '0px',
  left: '0px',
  bottom: '0px',
  right: '0px'
});
```

Comment: you can try :  angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("alert-backdrop"))

Comment: @HanyHabib, this is a library. I can not change anything in it((

Comment: what is the library name? is it something global to check the documentation

Comment: angular.element (jquery-lite) does not have .css. If you include jquery, then angular.element will use that (and .css will work). Or use vanilla js:  `backdropElement[0].style.position = "fixed"; // and so on... ` or even `backdropElement[0].style.cssText = cssString;`

Comment: @HanyHabib, Library: 'angular-strap'